# Visual Studio - compiler warnings for entire solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I build entire solution in Visual Studio compiler does not show all warnings. It shows warning only for opened files, if file is closed compiler warning is not present.

For example I have following line of code:

```
this.UpdateAsync();
```

and this call lacks await. This produces

> Compiler Warning CS4014

But this is only visible in Error list only if file is open. I would like to analyze entire solution like this, I have found no way yet - just open each file.

I tried to run Code Analysis on solution, but no luck, I have Warning level 4 on Project and Code analysis is enabled on build.

Is there any way to analyze entire solution for this warning?

We're using .NET 4.5.2 so cannot use Roslyn analyzers yet.

Comment: "Is there any way to analyze entire solution for this warning?" Sure, by *compiling* the entire solution.

Comment: @HimBromBeere "If I build entire solution in Visual Studio compiler does not show all warnings"

Comment: Are you sure you've got warnings enabled in your error list, and that it's set to show errors/warnings for the entire solution? Can you provide a screenshot of the top of your error list window?

Comment: What version of VS are you running?

Comment: I use VS2015. By compiling the entire solution I do not get such warning for files that are not open at the moment.

Comment: Do you have full solution analysis enabled? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx

Comment: You've tried a Clean and Rebuild All?

Comment: @mjwills this seems to help, thanks a million